# Can I detect shapes in an image using gd php

Tags: php, image, image-processing, computer-vision, object-detection

[image]

I am doing a program in php where i am taking an image from an IP camera and I am using gd php to draw a rectangle at certain x,y values. Is it possible to detect if the car moves in/out of the bounding box? or better yet is there a way that I can actually detect shapes (like a car) at the lot spots?

I am a little confused because people say gd is great but when I looked through the library I didn't see many functions at all.

thank you in advnace.

Comment: This is pretty advanced stuff, GD is only really built to create images, not analyze them.

Comment: Yes I figured . I can get it to work in JavaScript canvas but it does me no good I need these done server side because it runs in the background  and saves the info .. Do you know if any libraries that would be a viable solution to handle this .?

Comment: If you know how to do it with JS and you want to do it serverside, I would advise you to use NodeJS.
NodeJS can run as a background daemon and you write all your code in JS. 

Like scrowler said, I'm not sure PHP can do stuff like that, especially not with GD

Comment: I would agree .. However I am doing this for a company that absolutely insists I use their infrastructure ,  meaning I'm stuck w php .. :(

Comment: @Dnaso can you give reference to how you would do this in JS ?  It would be really useful to me and I'm sure others if this question had more of an explanation written up against it.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly not memory or super fast, but perhaps taking / making a hashmap of the pixel colors at certain points within your rectangle

Example:

Rectangle size: 200px by 200px
Plots:      0x0, 0x50, 0x100,0x150, 0x200, 50x0, 50x50, 50x100, etx.

At each plot record the color average within X points around your plot ( this should help prevent noise causing false positives.

then if at anypoint the map of colors you have is equal to empty plot, then your car is probably gone.

I understand that this question is old, but it was semi-close to a project I'm working on, as such I decided to leave an answer for someone in the future.